# How to use Beautiful Soup to extract info out of this in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<font class="detDesc">Uploaded 10-29&nbsp;18:50, Size 4.36&nbsp;GiB, ULed by <a class="detDesc" href="/user/NLUPPER002/" title="Browse NLUPPER002">NLUPPER002</a></font>
```

I need the 
Uploaded 10-29 18:50, Size 4.36 GiB and NLUPPER002 in two separate arrays. How do I do it?

Edit:

This is a part of a html page that has a lot of these html font tags with different values. I need a generic solution, if any using soup. Else, as suggested, I would look into regex.

Edit2:

I've a doubt along side this. If we use "class" as a key to traverse a soup, won't it class with the python keyword class and throw-up an error?

Comment: regular expressions could help you do this easily.

Comment: @JohnRiselvato no, regex is almost never a good solution for parsing XML/HTML

Comment: I can dump it as JSON but that still won't solve my solution as the HTML for this page is not that well written. Or so I think!

Comment: *"I need the Uploaded 10-29 18:50, Size 4.36 GiB and NLUPPER002 in two separate arrays"* -- so the output you expect is two lists, one containing all the "Update..." strings and another all the "NLUPPER..." strings?

Comment: Array separation is not a problem here. That I can manage. Your code explained to me how to reach to that particular hashtag (font) and access the values. That is the more than enough.

Comment: ok. Glad you find a solution.

Comment: @ShawnChin he could have done info between first > < then between the second > <, that way you wouldn't have to worry about change in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(your_data)
uploaded = []
link_data = []
for f in soup.findAll("font", {"class":"detDesc"}):
    uploaded.append(f.contents[0]) 
    link_data.append(f.a.contents[0])
```

For example, using the following data:

```
your_data = """
<font class="detDesc">Uploaded 10-29&nbsp;18:50, Size 4.36&nbsp;GiB, ULed by <a class="detDesc" href="/user/NLUPPER002/" title="Browse NLUPPER002">NLUPPER002</a></font>
<div id="meow">test</div>
<font class="detDesc">Uploaded 10-26&nbsp;19:23, Size 1.16&nbsp;GiB, ULed by <a class="detDesc" href="/user/NLUPPER002/" title="Browse NLUPPER002">NLUPPER003</a></font>
"""
```

running the code above gives you:

```
>>> print uploaded
[u'Uploaded 10-29&nbsp;18:50, Size 4.36&nbsp;GiB, ULed by ', u'Uploaded 10-26&nbsp;19:23, Size 1.16&nbsp;GiB, ULed by ']
>>> print link_data
[u'NLUPPER002', u'NLUPPER003']
```

To get the text in the exact form as you mentioned, you can either post-process the list or parse the data within the loop itself. For example:

```
>>> [",".join(x.split(",")[:2]).replace("&nbsp;", " ") for x in uploaded]
[u'Uploaded 10-29 18:50, Size 4.36 GiB', u'Uploaded 10-26 19:23, Size 1.16 GiB']
```

---

P.S. if you're a fan of list comprehension, the solution can be expresses as a one-liner:

```
output = [(f.contents[0], f.a.contents[0]) for f in soup.findAll("font", {"class":"detDesc"})]
```

This gives you:

```
>>> output  # list of tuples
[(u'Uploaded 10-29&nbsp;18:50, Size 4.36&nbsp;GiB, ULed by ', u'NLUPPER002'), (u'Uploaded 10-26&nbsp;19:23, Size 1.16&nbsp;GiB, ULed by ', u'NLUPPER003')]

>>> uploaded, link_data = zip(*output)  # split into two separate lists
>>> uploaded
(u'Uploaded 10-29&nbsp;18:50, Size 4.36&nbsp;GiB, ULed by ', u'Uploaded 10-26&nbsp;19:23, Size 1.16&nbsp;GiB, ULed by ')
>>> link_data
(u'NLUPPER002', u'NLUPPER003')
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. I like the solution given by @acorn too using lxml. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The expression you need to use to find the elements you're interested in depends on what is unique about those elements compared to other elements in the document. Therefore without the context of the element, it's difficult to help.

Are the elements you're interested in the only ones in the documents that are `font` elements and have a class of `detDesc`?

If so, here is a solution using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/):

```
import lxml.html as lh

html = '''
<font class="detDesc">Uploaded 10-29&nbsp;18:50, Size 4.36&nbsp;GiB, ULed by <a class="detDesc" href="/user/NLUPPER002/" title="Browse NLUPPER002">NLUPPER002</a></font>
'''

tree = lh.fromstring(html)

results = []

# iterate over all elements in the document that have a class of "detDesc"
for el in tree.xpath("//font[@class='detDesc']"):

    # extract text from the font element
    first = el.text

    # extract text from the first <a> within the font element
    second = el.xpath("a")[0].text

    results.append((first, second))

print results
```

**Result:**

```
[(u'Uploaded 10-29\xa018:50, Size 4.36\xa0GiB, ULed by ', 'NLUPPER002')]
```

Comment: Yes. Perfect solution. I can use the same concept at other places where I've used beautifulSoup. Or will that be a bad idea?

Comment: And by other places I mean, I use soup.findAll('a', title = 'something'), to take out all the links with the particular title which is repetitive.

Comment: lxml is a great alternative to beautifulSoup. Use whatever you're comfortable with. lxml uses powerful `xpath` selectors (and also allows css selectors), beautifulSoup uses its own special find methods with search parameters.